# Liferay unresolve requirement: Import package

Tags: liferay-7

I have a module in 7.2 Liferay environment, in the modules folder. I've compiled everything by running the commands:
1 - blade gw jar inside the modules folder
2 - gradlew distBundle
3- gradle deploy

From there I get into the Tomcat directory and get the following error:

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: cuatroochenta.rest [1141] _ Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.asset.category.property.model; version = "[2.1.0,3.0.0)" _ [Sanitized]

I have been searching but the information it gives regarding the error is also not very clear and I have not found an explicit solution.

Any ideas ??
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

add below lines in bnd.bnd file of your module :

`Import-Package: \
  !com.liferay.asset.category.*,\
  !com.liferay.asset.category.property.*,\
  *`

Note:- need to add all those packages who show unResolved Requirement.

Comment: I am facing same problem but the issue is whichever library I use it shows unresolved requirement in those. So, I cant do this in bnd.bnd any alternative to get rid off this ?